# Publishing additional message beside LaunchApp to the NFC tag makes first written message erased

Tags: c#, .net, nfc, ndef

I wanted to write to a NFC tag information about which application should start and add some text data to it. LaunchApp was working fine till I want to transmitt this additional message. When I added additional message `LaunchApp` stopped working. It is better explained in the code at the end of: `private void LaunchMesssageTransmitted(ProximityDevice sender, long publishedMessageId)`

How to make LaunchApp work and pass this string: `GlobaIPTextBox.Text + ";" + PortTextBox.Text + ";" + LocalIPTextBox.Text` to the tag.

```
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
        private long subscribedMessageID, publishedMessageId;
        private ProximityDevice proximityDevice;
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            createTagService();
        }

        private void createTagService() {
            string appId = "{39989b95-a54a-4810-b4ee-35b33265a680}";//HomeSecurityClient Application ID
            string args = "param=test";
            string launchAppMessage = args + "\tWindowsPhone\t" + appId;
            DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter() { UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf16LE };
            dataWriter.WriteString(launchAppMessage);
            proximityDevice = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
            proximityDevice.PublishBinaryMessage("LaunchApp:WriteTag", dataWriter.DetachBuffer(), LaunchMesssageTransmitted);
        }

        private void LaunchMesssageTransmitted(ProximityDevice sender, long publishedMessageId) {
            sender.StopPublishingMessage(publishedMessageId);
 /*           Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter() { UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8 };
                dataWriter.WriteString(GlobaIPTextBox.Text + ";" + PortTextBox.Text + ";" + LocalIPTextBox.Text);
                sender.PublishBinaryMessage("Windows:WriteTag.NetworkData", dataWriter.DetachBuffer(), networkDataMessageTransmitted);
            });*/ //IF I UNCOMMENT THIS TO TRANSMITT ADDITIONAL MESSAGE LAUNCHING APP STOPS WORKING

        }
        private void networkDataMessageTransmitted(ProximityDevice sender, long publishedMessageId) {
            sender.StopPublishingMessage(publishedMessageId);
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                MessageBox.Show("The data is written");
            });
            sender.StopPublishingMessage(publishedMessageId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write two seperate NDEF messages onto one tag. The last message will always overwrite any previous message. What you can do, however, is to write both records (the LaunchApp record and your customized record) to the tag within one NDEF message. For this to work, you would use the `PublishBinaryMessage()` method together with the message type "NDEF:WriteTag". That way you can pass the properly formatted(!) NDEF message to the tag. A way to create a properly formatted NDEF message would be to use the free NFC library from http://ndef.mopius.com/.